# How to put new string between commas in original string

Tags: java

I have this original string and I want to insert new string between two dots of original string. I did it this way, but having errors.

```
String originalString ="asdASfasdlpe.hereNeedToPutNewString.asdasfdfepw";
String stringForReplace = "NewString";
String new = originalString.replace(originalString.substring(originalString.indexOf(".") + 1), stringForReplace);
it gives me: "asdASfasdlpe.NewString"

Result should be: "asdASfasdlpe.NewString.asdasfdfepw"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like so.

- from the question it looks like you want to replace the first occurrence so use `replaceFirst`
- `(?<=\\.)` - look behind assertion - so start with following character
- `(?=\\.)`  - look ahead assertion - so end prior to that
- `.*?`   - reluctant quantifier to limit to just characters between two periods. Use `*` in case you have two adjacent periods since the string could be empty.

```
String s = "first.oldstring.third.fourth.fifth";
String n = "second";
s = s.replaceFirst("(?<=\\.).*?(?=\\.)",n);
System.out.println(s);
```

prints

```
first.second.third.fourth.fifth
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You go:

```
String new = originalString.replace(originalString.substring(originalString.indexOf(".") + 1), stringForReplace)+originalString.substring(originalString.indexOf(".",originalString.indexOf(".")+1),originalString.length());
```

What I have done is adding the resultant string to the new String.`indexOf` function takes another argument too, which is the position the search will start

Answer (score 0):

```
String originalString ="asdASfasdlpe.hereNeedToPutNewString.asdasfdfepw";
String stringForReplace = "NewString";
String a[]=originalString.split("[.]");
String newString="";
if(a.length==3) {
newString=originalString.replace(a[1], stringForReplace);
}
System.out.println(newString);
```

Or with ternary operator:

```
newString=(a.length== 3 ? originalString.replace(a[1], stringForReplace):null);
System.out.println(newString);
```

Answer (score 0):

One shorter solution is to use regex with a lookahead and lookbehind

```
String replaced = originalString.replaceAll("(?<=\\.).+(?=\\.)", stringForReplace);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is due to using this particular piece of code:

> originalString.substring(originalString.indexOf(".") + 1)

The reason is that indexof() function will only give the index on which **"."** was found on, and substring will only know where to start taking the substring from, but it wouldn't know where to end it.

Try this:

```
String originalString ="asdASfasdlpe.hereNeedToPutNewString.asdasfdfepw";
String stringForReplace = "NewString";
String newString = originalString.replace(originalString.split("[.]", 3)[1], stringForReplace);
System.out.println(newString);
```

The split function in this piece of code will break the whole string by **"."**
and you will have the string you want to replace available to you.

> originalString.split("[.]", 3)[1]

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String originalString ="asdASfasdlpe.hereNeedToPutNewString.asdasfdfepw";
    String stringForReplace = "NewString";
    String newStr = originalString.replaceAll("(?<=\\.).*(?=\\.)", stringForReplace);
    //using lookahead and lookbehind regex
    String newStr2 = originalString.replaceAll("\\..*\\.", "."+stringForReplace+".");
    System.out.println(newStr);
    System.out.println(newStr2);
}
```

One option uses lookahead and lookbehinds, you could opt to not use that if it is not supported.

Output:

```
asdASfasdlpe.NewString.asdasfdfepw
asdASfasdlpe.NewString.asdasfdfepw
```

Comment: Side note: assuming OP wants to replace only *once* `replaceFirst` would be preferred over `replaceAll` (in case additional `.` can appear).

Comment: I see... noted.

Comment: also noted that the regex above could potentially cause problems if there are multiple parts to replace. ```originalString = "asdASfasdlpe.hereNeedToPutNewString.hereNeedToPutNewString.asdasfdfepw"``` would give output ```asdASfasdlpe.NewString.asdasfdfepw``` it might just be easier to use split()